# How to recover files from the compressed NTFS partition?

Tags: windows, ntfs, compression, partition-recovery

One of the NTFS partitions was compressed with the tool implemented in Windows 7, available in the partition properties window.

Later, one of the folders has disappeared. I was trying to use Piriform Recuva with Deep Scan mode, and it has found some hashes (I thinks those files are related to Mozilla Thunderbird) and some files which looks like "f_XXXXXX" where "X" is hex number, and files are named in a row e.g. f_000009, f_00000a (there is no extension; exact, previous location is unknown).
How those compressed files should look like when I will find them? What software you can advise me to recover those lost files?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, data recovery tools unaware of the specific compression algorithms used in NTFS encryption will lose much of their functionality when accessing the disk in low-level mode. Low-level access will return compressed binary stream instead of the content of actual files, effectively rendering signature-search algorithms completely useless. Data recovery tools unaware of NTFS compression will fail to recover compressed files in a case the file system is broken.

Tools and Limitations

But it does not mean that compressed NTFS files cannot be recovered, EaseUS claims to be able to do that, however, the recovery of NTFS-compressed files carries a number of restrictions and limitations, it will be able to access and recover compressed files under certain conditions. For example, undeleting compressed files located on a healthy disk is no different to undeleting any other type of file. Recovering NTFS-compressed files from formatted NTFS disks is generally not a problem. However, if the file system is badly damaged, the chances of correctly recovering NTFS-compressed files are lower than those for non-compressed ones. It’s always worth a try to see if your files in your situation are actually recoverable.

Source：http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/recover-ntfs-compressed-file.htm

Let me know if it helps.